# Why can't I eat cake in Minecraft pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't eat cake in Minecraft PE. My version is 0.10.4. Does it have anything to do with the version I have?

Comment: Are you placing it on the ground first?

Answer (score 3):

To eat cake you need to place it on the ground.

After it has been placed you can eat it by tapping it repeatedly.

Don't long press it because that won't work.